# Matrix form of elementwise derivations

Tags: derivative, gradient, matrix-calculus

The elementwise derivations w.r.t e of $$ J = \frac{1}{2}[\Sigma_{r,s=1}^{R}a_{rt}a_{st}k(e_r,e_s) - 2\Sigma_{r=1}^{R}a_{rt}k(e_r, x_t)]$$

can be given by:

$$ \frac{\partial J}{\partial e_r} = \Sigma_{m=1}^{R}a_{mt}\frac{\partial}{\partial e_r} k(e_r,e_m) - \frac{\partial}{\partial e_r} k(e_r, x_t)$$

with $\frac{\partial}{\partial e} k(e, z) = \frac{-1}{\sigma^2} k(e, z)(e - z)$

What would be the matrix form of the above elementwise derivations?